# Finding the brightest spot in an image

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, numpy, simplecv

so I am trying to find the brightest spot in an image and get its coordinates. 
I already found a prewritten code but it doesn't work propoerly, I was wondering if anybody can give me a solution (I am not too advanced in programming) . 
Also I am using a video of a tracked object not just a photo.

This is the code I am trying to use:

```
# import the necessary packages
import SimpleCV
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2


display = SimpleCV.Display()
cam = SimpleCV.Camera()
img = cv2.imread(args["image"]).flipHorizontal().toGray()

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", help = "path to the image file")
ap.add_argument("-r", "--radius", type = int,
     help = "radius of Gaussian blur; must be odd")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# perform a naive attempt to find the (x, y) coordinates of
# the area of the image with the largest intensity value
(minVal, maxVal, minLoc, maxLoc) = cv2.minMaxLoc(gray)
cv2.circle(image, maxLoc, 5, (255, 0, 0), 2)

# display the results of the naive attempt
cv2.imshow("Naive", image)

# apply a Gaussian blur to the image then find the brightest
# region
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (args["radius"], args["radius"]), 0)
(minVal, maxVal, minLoc, maxLoc) = cv2.minMaxLoc(gray)
image = orig.copy()
cv2.circle(image, maxLoc, args["radius"], (255, 0, 0), 2)

# display the results of our newly improved method
cv2.imshow("Robust", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

but the error I am getting if I am trying to run it is:

```
NameError: the name 'args' is not defined
```

This is the original code which only uses photos:

```
# import the necessary packages
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2

 # construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
 ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
 ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", help = "path to the image file")
 ap.add_argument("-r", "--radius", type = int,
    help = "radius of Gaussian blur; must be odd")
 args = vars(ap.parse_args())

 # load the image and convert it to grayscale
 image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
 orig = image.copy()
 gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

 # perform a naive attempt to find the (x, y) coordinates of
 # the area of the image with the largest intensity value
 (minVal, maxVal, minLoc, maxLoc) = cv2.minMaxLoc(gray)
 cv2.circle(image, maxLoc, 5, (255, 0, 0), 2)

 # display the results of the naive attempt
 cv2.imshow("Naive", image)

# apply a Gaussian blur to the image then find the brightest
# region
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (args["radius"], args["radius"]), 0)
(minVal, maxVal, minLoc, maxLoc) = cv2.minMaxLoc(gray)
image = orig.copy()
cv2.circle(image, maxLoc, args["radius"], (255, 0, 0), 2)

# display the results of our newly improved method
cv2.imshow("Robust", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Your `img = cv2.imread(args...)` line needs to come *after* `args = vars...`

Comment: You are right, thank you! 
It still get further error Messages, I guess the probelm is, that I tried to modify the original code since it was only for photos. I wanted to delet the lines where it loads the photo and add lines so it accesses the camera instead. Seems like it didn't work out. I will add the original code to the above!